# Can PHPExcel add a trend line on a line chart?

Tags: php, charts, phpexcel

At the moment of this writing the current version of [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) is version 1.8.0. I know how to make a chart and embed it in a worksheet, I basically followed the [provided example](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Tests/33chartcreate.php) and modified it to create a line chart with multiple lines / data series based on a table of numbers.

Now what I would like to know is: how to add an average line / trend line over one of the lines of my line chart? Is this possible with PHPExcel 1.8.0 using the 'Excel2007' writer?

Comment: Trendline functionality isn't available in PHPExcel, so "No"

Comment: And technically, at the moment of writing the current version of PHPExcel is 1.8.1, but it isn't available as a full download package from codeplex any more, just from github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @MarkBaker in the comments, the answer to the question is "no" (at least not in version 1.8.1).

In my use case I was using PHP to generate an Excel workbook based on some processed data from different sources. What I did is to add VBA in `Sub Workbook_Open()` on the generated workbook to add the trend line. Then I used `PHPExcel->getMacrosCode()` to export the binary string of macro code to some file.

Now when generating files I add that binary string with `PHPExcel->getMacrosCode(String)` and save it as `.xlsm` instead of `.xlsx`. It is a bit of a hassle, but this is how I work around this problem for me.

Note that depending on your use case you might also need to generate a certificate to sign the code, to allow your user to always trust macros.